# How to model and solve this flower offerings to gods word problem?

Tags: exponential-function, mathematical-modeling, word-problem

So I came across this word problem and would like to get some help defining the model behind it and how to solve it.

> There is a temple, whose premises have a garden and a pond. It has 4
>   idols, each of Ram, Shiv, Vishnu and Durga. The priest plucks x
>   flowers from the garden and places them in the pond. The number of
>   flowers doubles up, and he picks y flowers out of them and goes to
>   offer it to Lord Ram. By the time he reaches to the pond, he finds the
>   remaining flowers also have doubled up in the meantime, so he again
>   picks up y from the pond and goes to Lord Shiv. This process is
>   repeated till all the Gods have y flowers offered to them, such that
>   in the end no flower is left in the pond. Find x and y.

I got as far as:

```
epoch0, x flowers
epoch1, 2(2x-y) flowers
epoch2, 2(2(2x-y)-y) flowers
epoch3, 2(2(2(2x-y)-y)-y) flowers
epoch4, 2(2(2(2(2x-y)-y)-y)-y) flowers
```

Then I thought of setting epoch4 to 0. But I know I need another equation since there are two unknowns. Also, I have a hunch I could also use an exponential growth equation but the constant "withdrawals" is something I have not seen before. Im kinda stuck and would appreciate any tips!

The answer is (base64 encoded): eD0xNSx5PTE2

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions, no?

Comment: @uniquesolution yes there are multiple... but what would be the mechanics/method to even get one? Is my model correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a linear difference equation $x_{n+1}=2x_n-y$ where $x_0=x$

Let $z_n = x_n -c$ for some constant $c$ which we will determine.

Then $z_{n+1}+c=2(z_n+c)-y\implies z_{n+1} + c = 2z_n + 2c -y$

Setting $c=2c-y$ gives $c=y$ and, moreover, we get that $z_{n+1}=2z_n$

From this we get that $z_n=2^nz_0\implies x_n-y=2^n(x_0-y)$

Now we can plug in $n=4$ and use the fact that $x_4=0$ to solve for $y$ to get

$$-y = 16(x-y)\implies 15y=16x$$

Any whole numbers $x$ and $y$ that satisfy this equation will work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that if the priest plucks $15$ flowers from the garden and places them in the pond, upon which they double up, and then he picks $16$ out of them and gives them to Ram. When he comes back, there are $28$ in the pond. He picks $16$ again, and gives them to Shiv.  He comes back, there are $24$. He picks $16$ again, and gives them to Vishnu, only to find $16$ flowers in the pond, which he gladly takes and hands over to the fourth lord, Durga. I came up with this solution by noticing that the series you wrote comes down to $16x-15y$ after the fourth step.